# How does a cloud based application execute ?

Tags: cloud, ms-office

What I would like to learn is how does the mechanics of a cloud based application execution actually work ? Does the application (Microsoft Office for example Word) and associated files execute and reside at the workstation level of the customer or does the application and all of its components resides somewhere on the cloud software or somewhere on the cloud based providers IAAS ? And can anyone explain where does virtualization come into the picture in all of this ?

Answer (score 0):

When describing a cloud based application, it usually means that the files do not reside or execute at the workstation level.  A common (simplified) architecture is to have a front end loaded at the workstation level and the front end makes API (application programming interface) calls to the back end cloud services.  The back end services perform work and update what you see on the front end. [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_services) and [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) are examples of protocols used to communicate with a remote service, in the cloud in this case.

IAAS lets you provision virtual machines in the cloud.  IAAS is said to be close to bare metal since working with virtual machines is like working with servers.  On those virtual machines, you can host your own back end services.  PAAS (platform as a service) and SAAS (software as a service) are farther away from bare metal and instead of worrying about installing operating system updates and software patches, you can use a platform for loading your software or use the software directly.  Of course, behind all the PAAS and SAAS is IAAS, its just managed by someone else instead of you.